# Removeing ulimit from boot / init

Tags: centos, service, linux-kernel, ulimit, init

In CentOs as from version 6 there is a by default process limit 1024 for every user i.e /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf

```
*          soft    nproc   1024
```

I have to execute a backend service/daemon "myservice", which require a bigger value in process limits. So I have to override pre-configured limit (1024). For that purpose I tried to create separate entries for root and myuser ( user running myservice ).

```
myuser          soft    nproc   5000
root            soft    nproc   5000
```

and then

```
service myservice restart
```

now limit was increased and seems that issue has been solved! but it was temporarily, after system reboot limit was again to 1024. (**NOTE:** myservice was configured to start at boot)

It seems that it happened due to init process who is responsible to start each service on system, hence "myserivce" as a child inherited parent's limits (init has 1024 limit by default).

I googled to find if there is any way to increase limits for init, but was not enough lucky to find any! I have tried to alter/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf

```
*          soft    nproc   5000
```

but still same, after reboot init still have 1024 limit and myservice also has 1024 limit

**NOTE:** if I restart myservice from shell prompt then it get accepted limits (5000) but I want to start it automatically after every reboot.

Can somebody guide me, How I can increase process limit for "myservice", and preserve it after reboot ?

Comment: Are you trying to increase the open file descriptor limit? (`nofile`) This seems to be your intent in the first sentence. Or, the [per-user process limit?](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/chap-Security_Guide-Securing_Your_Network.html#sect-Security_Guide-Workstation_Security-Applying_Account_Limits) (`nproc`)

Comment: actually I want to increase both, just mentioned one

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/589258/50647 ???

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem could be two-fold. You appear to only be increasing the soft limit but not the hard limit. If the hard limit default is lower than the defined soft limit, I think you will continue to be constrained by the lower value.

Also, these are the per-user limits but not necessarily the kernel's system-wide configured limit. You may need to set the value with the appropriate sysctl command. (Make it persistent in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.)

For example, this will set the Kernel's maximum for file descriptors. (The Kernel tracks processes with open files, so this same key is related for both ulimit values.

```
sysctl -w fs.file-max=10000
```

(I think this is likely to be the part that is lacking persistence in your current configuration based on its omission.)

Then, you can set the per-user limits in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

```
* soft nofile 2500
* hard nofile 5000
```

And `/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf`.

```
* soft nproc 2500
* hard nproc 5000
```

These values are examples only, of course and you can replace the asterisks with your user.